# How to let the chrome F12 developer tool log the NetWork When I input a download-link URL?

Tags: java, google-chrome, servlet-3.0

I want to see the request header and response header of `http://v.stu.126.net/mooc-video/nos/flv/2015/01/14/1156038_sd.flv?ak=1c3e5829d239ea680a1609dbf128a8cf795d9a7be01e34208908d10acc938420187e9fc2c03c131c05b00f2acdc210401ffe1176c1bd8eb4fafe9865becf1e29039e603a3dc588b01f3084ef1bab33e3d946cc99125d5cf199a7eb88f34ab25df0837682774232610f0d4e39d8436cb9a153bdeea4a2bfbae357803dfb6768a742fe395e87eba0c3e30b7b64ef1be06585111bf60ea26d5dad1f891edd9e94a8e167e0b04144490499ffe31e0d97a0a1babcbd7d2e007d850cc3bf7aa697e8ff`.
But it seems didn't trigger the Chrome's network logger. How can I see it?When you input the URL, the chrome just start to download the flv without any log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whatever the reason the simplest way to overcome it is just to create a local html file with a link to that resource. Open local file with browser, start chrome developer tools and just click the link.

Comment: Good idea! if you have any better idea someday, please tell me. thx